# Laravel Backpack - Preselect field from filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

Is there any way to preselect a `select` or other field value when creating a new entity based on the applied filters?

I am trying to ease the work when adding multiple new records in Backpack and pre-filling some data base on the filters applied to the listing would help me a lot.

Comment: what did you try? show us some code. You could always make a custom select field and add as many params as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to natively do that, but you could customize things to achieve this:

- overwrite the create button by having a file in your `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/buttons/create.blade.php` so that you could place an ID on that button, say... `#crud_add_button`;
- insert some javascript in your `public/vendor/backpack/crud/js/list.js` that upon DataTable filtering (or search) it places all the GET parameters on the `#create_add_button` too;
- this way, when you click the add button the URL could look like `http://backpackapp.local/admin/monster/create?draft=1,category=23`; that's what would actually get clicked by the user;
- in your EntityCrudController, have a `create()` method that overwrites the one in CrudController; this method could set `default` parameters on each field, based on the GET parameters, then `return parent::create()`; [note: this method might not even be needed, since I believe Laravel merges GET, POST and OLD parameters, and `default` is already configured to pick up the value if it's in a parameter; but I'm not sure];

Hope it helps.